# IE Flexbox - Child Element does not stretch when using min-height on parent

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

Please have a look at this pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYZLMG

What it should do is make the red `.section` element fill the blue `.container` element. It works in Chrome and FF, but not in IE.

When setting `height` instead of `min-height`, it works, but I need `min-height` because the contained elements might exceed an thus increase the size of the container.

Is there a way to make that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix that, I needed to wrap the `min-height` element in another flexbox row.

http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/cf5b323f92549ea4b9e9aa3afcee9fc41427899803437/index.html#https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#3-min-height-on-a-column-flex-container-wont-apply-to-its-flex-items

Not beautiful because I have to add another element just for "styling", however it works.

Comment: Will do, but it makes me wait 3 days before I am allowed to -.-

Comment: page not found(